# how to make vagrant use bash and resolve `[[: not found`?

Tags: bash, vagrant

I am using vagrant and my script outputs `[[: not found`.

I understand it is because I am using shell for script that should use bash.

I made sure I have a shebang for bash `#!/usr/bin/env bash` but I am still getting that error.

I tried replacing `config.vm.provision "shell"` to `config.vm.provision "bash"` but got `provisioner could not be found.`

What am I supposed to do?

**details about the script**

I am using cloudbees' node installation snippet

```
curl -s -o ./use-node https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/node/use-node
NODE_VERSION=0.10.24 . ./use-node
```

The `use-node` script has the line `if [[ -z $NODE_VERSION ]]; then`

I am aware I can install node myself - that would definitely be the work around unless I get vagrant to execute with bash like I want.

Comment: Where is the script? Have you looked at [this](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html)? Doesn't look like the `bash` provisioner exists. You should be able to do what you want without using `[[`

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems to me your shebang is off. Try `bash_path=$(which bash) && sed "1s/.*/#! $bash_path/" script.sh` and execute again (script.sh is the name of your script in `.`).

Comment: You need to add an `-i` flag to that `sed` command in my previous comment, sorry.

Comment: Also you need to use a different delimiter, because the path contains slashes.  But anyway, the `env` shebang is fine; this is a red herring.

Comment: did the steps manually. `which bash` was `/bin/bash` and I changed my shebang to `#!/bin/bash` still no good.

Comment: The shebang is ignored, because `use-node` is sourced.

Answer (score 3):

If the script only contains trivial bashisms, you can simply rewrite it to `sh`-compatible, and change the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`.

Change

```
if [[ -z $NODE_VERSION ]]; then
```

to

```
if [ -z "$NODE_VERSION" ]; then
```

(The double quotes should properly be used in the Bash version too.)

However, recognizing and fixing Bashisms in a large script is potentially a nontrivial endeavour.

If the script is specifically bash-only, you can create a wrapper for it, like

```
#!/bin/sh
exec env bash /path/to/real/script
```

which solves the problem at the cost of an ugly extra layer of wrapping.  (The `env` is not strictly necessary here if you only used it to avoid having to put in the full path to `bash`, but there are probably situations where it has other useful effects, too.)

Comment: If you source the script with the bashism, a neat hack would be to write a simple function which (partially) reimplements `[[` but the semi-obvious `[[ () { [ "${@%\]}"; }` did not work in my copy of Dash (0.5.5.1-7.4 on Debian `squeeze`) ... The substitution does the wrong thing, and on top of that, it says `Syntax error: Bad function name`.

Comment: Such a simulated `[[` (if `[[` were a valid function name) would be unable to take advantage of most of the reasons `[[` is used (no word-splitting on parameter expansions, `=~`, pattern matching with `=`, etc).

Comment: Of course; this is only feasible as a quick and dirty workaround for a very limited scenario, such as gratuitous use of `[[ -z "$var" ]]` where just `[` would do fine.

Comment: I did manage to `alias [[=fun` in Dash but could not quickly come up with a good definition for `fun`.